# Exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to retrieve an attribute from servlet(viewcurrentstock.java) to jsp(viewstock.jsp).
here an exception is promted saying "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException"

[image]

viewcurrentstock.java

```
   ItemDBController itemDBController=new ItemDBController();
        try {
            List<Item> allItems = itemDBController.getAllItems();
            request.setAttribute("items",allItems);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("viewstock.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ViewCurrentStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

viewstock.jsp

```
<%ArrayList<Item> itemlist = (ArrayList<Item>) request.getAttribute("items"); %>
 <html>
  <head>
      </head> 
         <body>
       <table border="2">
         <tbody>
            <%for (Item item : itemlist) {%>
            <tr>
                  <td><%=item.getItemcode()%></td>
                  <td><%=item.getItemname()%></td>
                  <td><%=item.getDescription()%></td>
                   <td><%=item.getQtyOnHand()%> </td>
                   <td> <%= item.getReorderlevel()%></td>
                   <td><%=item.getUnitprice()%></td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
        </tbody>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

server log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.viewstock_jsp._jspService(viewstock_jsp.java:66)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Look at your server log and post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or **error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check if `itemDBController.getAllItems();` is actually returning list.

Comment: @Jens server log added!!

Comment: @RRR itemDBController.getAllItems(); is working!, displayed all the elements of the arrraylist using for each.

Comment: Can you find out wich line is 66 in `viewstock_jsp.java`

Comment: @Jens There's nothing at line 66 in viewstock_jsp.java

Comment: Might helpful :http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-debug-jsp-with-help-of-compiled.html

Comment: Do you looked into the jsp at line 66 or in the generated class?

Comment: @Jens it's jsp at line 66.where can i find the generated class

Comment: @KumaranathFernado I am not fimular with glassfish but there must be a folder named "generated/jsp/" under the glassfish home.

Comment: @Jens it would be much appreciated if you could provide a relative path

Comment: @KumaranathFernado You can find class files `\WEB-INF\classes` inside your war

Comment: @KumaranathFernado This must be the path: `{glassfish_home}/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/my_project/xyz_loader`

Answer (score 0):

Using scriplets is discouraged see here [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), print it out using jstl `forEach`

Add this for taglib support for jstl,

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

And simply,

```
<c:forEach var="temp" items="${items}">
<tr>
                 <td>${temp.itemcode}</td>
                  <td>${temp.get.name}</td>
                  <td>${temp.description}</td>
                   <td>${temp.qtyOnHand }</td>
                   <td>${temp.reorderlevel}</td>
                   <td>${temp.unitprice}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I am not sure with variables of your bean class . the syntax is `${var.AttributeName}` in the model class

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Any errors or exceptions . define `this did not work`